# How to add per-cell placeholders to a handsontable?

Tags: handsontable

I'm working on a small application that trains users to navigate around cells and enter predefined (placeholder) content.

I know that it's possible to add per-column placeholders but haven't found a way to add per-cell placeholders.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the placeholder to the cellProperties instead of the Column. I guess it should work. The cascading configuration should pick up the cell properties.
https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Options#how-does-cascading-configuration-work

Comment: I originally solved this problem by writing a custom `renderer` function and setting the classes of cells to a gray placeholderish color when no value was in the model but I've just checked that your solution does work and it seems to be cleaner than mine.